# Position child elements in header

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to recreate this simple website layout:[Website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUY7.png)

Within the header tag, I am having trouble lining up the logo image with the green image with the slogan on it, shown here: [failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlQdP.jpg).

Here is the code I have for that area:

```
header {
overflow: hidden; 
}
.container {
width: 780px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
.logo {
width: 347px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;  
}
.slogan {
background-image: url(images/header-vet.jpg);
padding: 15px;
float: left;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="header_img">
<img src="images/main-logo.jpg" alt="Vetinfo logo">
</div>
<div class="slogan">
Welcome to VetInfo
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: please post your html code as well

Comment: Thanks, just did.

Comment: add float:left to logo as well

Comment: @Shahil M For some reason that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for that:

```css
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.container {
  width: 780px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 347px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slogan {
  background-image: url(images/header-vet.jpg);
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header_img">
    <img src="images/main-logo.jpg" alt="Vetinfo logo">
  </div>
  <div class="slogan">
    Welcome to VetInfo
  </div>
</header>
```